# Obtaining Values from an Array

Tags: list, haskell

I am incredibly new to Haskell, and I am having trouble with some homework. I do not understand how to properly take in an array, and use the data with in it.

for example in java I would have something like

```java
int[] arr = {...};
arr[0];
arr[1];
```

In my Haskell problem I have

```hs
dot :: [Float] -> [Float] -> Float
-- enter code here
```

I can not find a way to use the data inside the float array. My professors example for this problem uses Vectors, but we have to use a `[Float]`

I'm not asking for anyone to do the problem, just an explanation on how to use the array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is technically speaking **not an array**, but a **(linked-)list**. That is something different. A list is defined as:

```
data [a] = [] | (a:[a])
```

So it is a data-type that has two constructors:

- the empty list `[]` which is used to signal the end of a list; and
- the `cons` that has two elements: an `a` (the item) and a reference to the tail (a `[a]`).

Now that we know that you can use **pattern** matching to extract elements (and do tests). For instance in the following function:

```
head :: [a] -> a
head (x:_) = x
```

Here `head` expects to see a `cons` construct and it *extracts* the head (the element of the first node) and returns that. Or for instance:

```
second :: [a] -> a
second (_:(x:_)) = x
```

here again you use pattern matching to extract the second element.

Another way to obtain elements is using the [`(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-). operator. You can obtain the *i*-th element (zero-based), by using:

```
list!!i
```

which is equivalent to `list[i]` in Java semantically. Mind however that - as said before - these are linked lists, so obtaining the *i*-th element requires *O(i)* computational effort. Although this may look like a detail it can become a bit dramatic when you want to fetch an object with a large index. Furthermore since `(!!)` is called, you are less certain there is such element: you have not that much guarantees that the list is indeed long enough. It is therefore wise to use pattern matching and look for clever ways to exploit the linked list data structure.

For your example for the dot product, you can for instance first use pattern matching like:

```
dot (x:xs) (y:ys) = ...
```

and so you have extracted the *heads* `x` and `y` from the lists. And then you can multiply them and add them to the dot product of the remainder of the list:

```
dot (x:xs) (y:ys) = x*y + dot xs ys
```

now you only still need to define **base case(s)** like for instance:

```
dot [] [] = 0.0
```

so putting it all together:

```
dot :: [Float] -> [Float] -> Float
dot [] [] = 0.0
dot (x:xs) (y:ys) = x*y + dot xs ys
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't even think to do a base case. I had seen the (x:xs) before, but was not sure exactly what it meant. This is probably the most informative answer I have ever gotten on stackoverflow. Thank you!

Comment: Note that this doesn't handle the cases where the lists are different lengths.  You should probably consider how to do that, even if it's not needed for the assignment.

Comment: @Carl: Well I left that out deliberately since the *dot product* over two vectors with different length is rather undefined. You can assume that the "virtual tails" contain zeros, but it is likely something is wrong with the code that generates the vectors.